# How to build Vue.js links in a separate div?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I want to create a static header, with some links that change a `vue app` like a `SPA`. I know how to do this within the main app, but how can it be achieved outside of it, in a static header for example?

App being the main `vue` instance.

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
       <a href="" id="link_to_change_app_view"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="#app"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: well you can't that's why you put everything inside the app or mount your app to the body. If you want a static header just place it above your router view and there you go

Comment: I see now, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As claimed in the comments you can simply put your static header inside your app

```
<div id="#app">
   <!-- static -->
   <div id="header">
     <router-link to="" id="link_to_change_app_view" />
   </div>

   <!-- dynamic -->
   <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```